# Twice differentiable function not equal to $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

This is a question in the undergraduate-level textbook "Advanced Calculus" by Fitzpatrick.

Suppose that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable such that for $\forall x$, $f'(x)\leq f(x)$, and $f(0)=0$. Then is $f$ the zero function?

The answer to this is not true as I was able to find a counter-example $f^*(x)= 1- e^x$. However we have only just learned about differentiation, the mean-value theorem and how to find extremes using 1st and 2nd derivatives, and we have only seen derivatives of polynomials so far, but I don't know how to disprove the above statement by using these.

(EDIT) For $1−e^x$ to be a valid counter-example, I need to "officially know" that the exponential function's derivative is equal to itself. But exponential functions are in the next chapter. Therefore unless I want to "cheat", I need to think of another function.

Comment: Read the question and think about what it is asking?

Comment: What is it that you mean?

Comment: He means the question is asking you to verify if $f(x)=0$ satisfies the conditions set out in the problem!

Comment: Your counter example is correct. You just need to add one more sentence in your answer: "from the counter-example given above it is evident that $f$ is not necessarily the zero function".

Comment: @Laars Helenius Wouldn't then saying "is the zero function a solution?", be a better statement then? I think that the question asks whether the conditions given as they are, overrule any possibility, other than zero, for the solution function..

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I don't think you understood my problem with the question here :)

Comment: I do understand it. Disproving something in general does not require theorems. One can disprove a statement by just giving a counter-example. So you have already solved the problem.

Comment: Do you want a counter example using polynomials?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh for $1-e^x$ to be a valid counter-example, I need to "officially know" that the exponential function's derivative is equal to itself. But exponential functions are in the next chapter. Therefore unless I want to "cheat", I need to think of another counter example. So yes, polynomials is what I'm struggling with..

Comment: That might be hard to figure out. Just update your question based on your last comment. Someone here might find the kind of counter-example you are looking for.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) =x^4$ for $x<0$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: @Jose27. Perfect. That should be an Answer.

Comment: @Jose27 Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morally any function that is positive an decreasing on $x<0$ and $0$ otherwise will be a counterexample. To satisfy the smoothness assumption just pick a function that goes to $0$ fast enough at $x=0$; for example $f(x)=x^4$ for $x<0$ and $0$ otherwise will do the trick.